# How to check progress of teacher in moodle

Tags: moodle

How to check the progress of teacher in moodle(teacher is active or not in moodle and gives activities to students etc. )
I didn't find any in moodle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the moodle reports to obtain information about teacher activity within specific courses. If you want to track all and every "teaching" action made by some user you can, for example, check the report **log** at `report/log/index.php` and then filter by user (select the teacher's fullname) and by event type: `teaching`, you can also filter by specific course and specific day.

On getting those logs you will see all actions for that teacher on that given time/course/etc. like, for example, grading of activities, activity view, course updating, course module creation and a long etc.

You may also download the report in CSV file format in case you need to do further data manipulation, like aggregations and so on.